# reinstall postgres on Amazon EC2 ubuntu server

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-14.04

While trying to install postgres on ubuntu server, I messed up and now I am getting the following error. How to fix the missing dependencies and move forward? My final aim is to install postgis.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-17-218:~$ sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql : Depends: postgresql-10 but it is not going to be installed
 postgresql-contrib : Depends: postgresql-contrib-10
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
ubuntu@ip-172-31-17-218:~$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the steps mentioned in the blog: http://www.gis-blog.com/how-to-install-postgis-2-3-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts and all the issue were solved.